# how to declare in c a separate function that convert upper in lowercases and count the uppercases which where converted?

Tags: c, count, c-strings, uppercase, function-definition

we have to declare in c a separate function that convert upper in lowercases and count the uppercases which where converted, but i can´t find my mistake..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char umwandlung(char text)
{
  int n, upper=0;

  if (text >= 65 && text <= 90)//upper in lowercases
  {
    text = text + 32;
  }
```

I´m not sure if my declaration to count the converted uppercase is right, i tried to copy and apply it to my code.. but it won't work

```
for (n=0; text[n]!=0; n++)
  {
    if (text[n] >= 'A' && text[n] <= 'Z')
    {
      upper++;
    }
  }
  printf("\n%i Buchstaben wurden geandert\n",upper);

  return text;
}

int main(void)
{
  char satz[80];
  int i, x, upper=0, n;

  printf("\ngross in klein \n");
  printf("Bitte geben Sie einen Satz mit max. 80 Zeichen ein:\n");
  gets(satz);
  x = strlen(satz);

  for (i = 0; i <= x; i++)
  {
    satz[i] = umwandlung(satz[i]);
  }

  printf("\n%s\n",satz);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function can be declared and defined the following way.

```
#include <ctype.h>

size_t to_lower_case( char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( ; *s; ++s )
    {
        if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*s ) )
        {
            *s = tolower( ( unsigned char )*s );
            ++n;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

and called like

```
size_t n = to_lower_case( satz );
```

Pay attention to that the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use the function `fgets` or `scanf`. Gor example

```
scanf( "%79[^\n]", satz );
```

Answer (score -1):

Your implementation doesn't work because your function has the signature:

`char umwandlung(char text)`. This means that your function receives a char as a parameter and returns a char. But your function needs the address of the string that you want to change and to return an `int` because I think your string could be larger, so it should be something like: `int umwandlung(char *text)`

Another problem is that you call your function for every character in that string so in this way you can't change anything in that string, maybe only to count the uppercase.

I will put below an implementation starting for your example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int umwandlung(char *text)
{
  int i, upper=0;

  for(i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
    if(text[i] >= 65 && text[i] <= 90) {
      text[i] += 32;
      upper++;
    }
  }

  return upper;
}



int main(void)
{
  char satz[80];
  int i, x, upper=0, n;

  printf("\ngross in klein \n");
  printf("Bitte geben Sie einen Satz mit max. 80 Zeichen ein:\n");
  fgets(satz, 80, stdin);

  upper = umwandlung(satz);

  printf("\n%i Buchstaben wurden geandert\n",upper);
  printf("\n%s\n",satz);

}
```

Don't use `gets` function anymore, it's already deprecated.

Comment: thank you, but would it also work with sprintf?

Comment: It is an example of how to do not write programs. Magic numbers & wrong types

Comment: @stusselmb I don't really understand where you want to use sprintf.

Comment: @0___________ yes, it's not the best format, but for a beginner, it's better to adapt their program to correct the issue, otherwise, it would be harder to understand. Easy steps.

Comment: @MocanuGabriel No it is not. You havethe correct Vlad's answer. Can you spot the difference